# Lemma in Petersen's *Ergodic Theory*

Tags: information-theory, ergodic-theory, entropy

I'm trying to understand the proof of Lemma 6.2.1 (p.260-261) in Petersen's *Ergodic Theory*. Specifically, I don't understand why $B_{n}^{A} \in \mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-n}\alpha)$ holds. Why does it?

Here's the setup:

- $(X,\mathscr{B}, \mu)$ is a probability space
- $T\colon X \to X$ is a measure-preserving ergodic transformation
- $\alpha$ is a countable measurable partition of $X$ with finite entropy
- $\mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-k}\alpha)$ denotes the $\sigma$-algebra generated by the common refinement of the partitions $T^{-1}\alpha, \dots, T^{-k}\alpha$.
- $B_{n}^{A} := \{x \colon f_{1}^{A}(x), \dots, f^{A}_{n-1} \leq \lambda, f_{n}^{A} > \lambda\}$, where $A\in \alpha$ is fixed and $\lambda \geq 0$
- $f_{k}^{A} = -\log \mu(A|T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-k}\alpha)$

So again, my question is:
**Why is $B_{n}^{A} \in \mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-n}\alpha)$?**

**Edit:** I really only need to understand this for the case where $T$ is the shift on Cantor space; i.e. $X=\{0,1\}^{\mathbb{N}}$. So an answer in this setting will suffice.

Comment: Is it clear to you that $f^A_k$ is $\mathscr B(T^{-1}\alpha\vee\dots\vee T^{-n}\alpha)|\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$-measurable for any $k\leq n$ and $A$? Note that $B_n^A$ is a pre-image of the function $(f_1^A,\dots,f_n^A)$.

Comment: @S.D. What does $\mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-n} \alpha)|\mathscr{B}(X)$-measurable mean? (I'm assuming your $\mathbb{R}$ should've been an $X$.)

Comment: Nope, I meant that the function $$f_k^A = -\log \mu (A|T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-k}\alpha):(X,\mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-k}\alpha))\to(\mathbb R,\mathscr{B}(\mathbb R))$$ is measurable, i.e. for any $B\in \mathscr{B}(\mathbb R)$ one has $(f^A_k)^{-1}(B)\in \mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-k}\alpha)$. $$$$ By the way, I've never seen notation with $\vee$ before. Did you mean that $$T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-k}\alpha = \{T^{-1}\alpha_1\cap\dots\cap T^{-k}\alpha_k|\alpha_1,\dots,\alpha_k\in \alpha\}$$ is the common refinement?

Comment: @S.D.Yes, that's what I meant by the symbol $\vee$. That is the notation used for common refinement in Petersen's, Walters', and Billingsley's books. I'm still thinking about the rest of your comments.

Comment: Take a look on the definition of measure $\mu(\cdot|\mathscr F)$ conditional some $\sigma$-algebra $\mathscr F$.

Comment: @S.D.For some reason, I was thinking of the statement as saying that $B^{A}_{n}$ was one of the elements of the partition $T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-n}\alpha$ (even though I knew $\mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-n}\alpha)$ denoted the $\sigma$-algebra generated by that partition). It's clear to me now that $B^{A}_{n} \in \mathscr{B}(T^{-1}\alpha \vee \dots \vee T^{-n}\alpha)$. Thus my question here is no longer open. Thanks for your help. If you post your first comment as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: Nice to be of help

Comment: @S.D. The notation $\vee$ is more generally commonly used to denote a supremum.

Comment: @StéphaneLaurent: I'm aware of that, as mush of its "disjunction" meaning, whereas here the "conjunction" $\wedge$ seems to be more appropriate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Using the definition of $f_k^A$ we see that it is $\mathscr B (T^{-1}\alpha\dots T^{-k}\alpha) |\mathscr B(\mathbb R)$-measurable function which implies the measurability of the map
$$
f = (f_1^A,\dots,f_n^A):(X,\mathscr B (T^{-1}\alpha\dots T^{-n}\alpha))\to(\mathbb R^n,\mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)).
$$
Finally, the set $C = (-\infty,\lambda]^{n-1}\times(\lambda,\infty)\in \mathscr B(\mathbb R^n)$ and $B_n^A = f^{-1}(C)$ which answers your question